# pandas: flatten df with delimiter

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My goal is to load a dataframe into a DB using a stdin pipe to a load statement executed at the command line (e.g. cat {file_loc} | /path/to/sql --command "COPY table FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',';"). I'm aware that this approach is suboptimal; it's a workaround due to pyodbc issues ;)

What's the most efficient way to condense a dataframe so that each row is a string that contains delimiter-separated values with line breaks at the end? My solution, below, seems inefficient.

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=(5,3)),columns=['A','B','C'])
df2 = df.apply(lambda d: ','.join([`x` for x in d]))
```

Writing the dataframe using df.to_csv() or similar is too slow...

```
import timeit
m1="""df2=df.apply(lambda d: ','.join([`x` for x in d]))"""
met1t = timeit.Timer(stmt=m1,setup="from pandas import *; import numpy as np; df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=(5,3)),columns=['A','B','C'])")
print "Method 1: %.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * met1t.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
# 381.82 usec/pass

m2="""df.to_csv('testout.csv', index=False, header=False)"""
met2t = timeit.Timer(stmt=m2,setup="from pandas import *; import numpy as np; df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=(5,3)),columns=['A','B','C'])")
print "Method 2:%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * met2t.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
# 551.30 usec/pass
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post data and speed comparison of to_csv vs what you're doing? Might be opportunity for optimization in to_csv.

Comment: @ChangShe: Updated w/ timeit results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you describe the pyodbc issues?

I created an issue here. To get the ultimate perf you'd want to drop down into C or Cython and build the raw byte string yourself using C string functions. Not very satisfying, I know. At some point we should build a better-performing to_csv for pandas, too:

http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2210

Comment: it was somethings specific to writing in our db but I never figured out the details. I'll try to investigate more and provide more specifics later.